# Webpack error "Chunk.entry was removed. Use hasRuntime()" on Heroku

Tags: heroku, webpack, html-webpack-plugin, extracttextwebpackplugin

I'm getting a build error when running webpack in trying to deploy a project to Heroku (and only then):

```
remote:        ERROR in chunk webpackManifest [entry]        
remote:        js/[name]-[chunkhash].js        
remote:        Chunk.entry was removed. Use hasRuntime()        
remote:        Child html-webpack-plugin for "../server/views/index.hbs"
```

It works fine for me locally, it's just on a Heroku dyno that it fails. It seems to have started failing when I started using HTMLWebpackPlugin in my build, and the error message seems to point to that module (as you can see). Googling the error gives a bunch of results, but they all seem to boil down to [this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2764) issue. That issue points to `extract-text-webpack-plugin` as the culprit, but the comments are all outdated and the suggestion (to install a beta or rc3 version of the plugin) doesn't work since extract-text-webpack-plugin seems to have passed that now. As far as I can tell, HTMLWebpackPlugin doesn't depend on extract-text-webpack-plugin at all.

EDIT: The Heroku install uses webpack@2.6.1, locally I was on 2.5.1, but manually changing to 2.6.1 locally still wasn't able to reproduce it.

EDIT 2: Explicitly upping the dependency in my `package.json` to `^2.7.0` seems to have made Heroku happy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this was some sort of temporary issue, since it seems to work if explicitly using the latest version.